# Symfony3: Display an image places in web/cache/media folder

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I am using ImagineBundle and I'm trying to display a filtered image.

My twig code is this:

```
<img src="{{ currentProfileImage|default|imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

Without the filter, the image is displayed correctly from the path:

```
<img src="/bundles/templates/uploads/images/my_folder/01c2b593148119e2dbcf40fef147542b.jpeg" />
```

But with the filter applyed, I get the following output:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/media/cache/my_thumb/bundles/templates/uploads/images/my-folder/01c2b593148119e2dbcf40fef147542b.jpeg" />
```

With the filter applied, the image is not displayed.. if I try to copy / paste in address bar the path: http://www.example.com/media/cache/my_thumb/bundles/templates/uploads/images/my-folder/01c2b593148119e2dbcf40fef147542b.jpeg

is says Route not Found..

I realised that any image that is not placed in web/bundles folder is not displayed..

Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE:
config.yml looks like this:

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    my_thumb:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: Have you tried the URL `http://www.example.com/bundles/templates/uploads/images/my_folder/01c2b593148119e2dbcf40fef147542b.jpeg`?

Comment: There is the original image, not resized, and it works. I want to display the resized image which is in we/cache/media... folder.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you forgot to add routing as mentioned in [LiipImagineBundle's description](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#configuration):

```
# app/config/routing.yml

_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

When using this bundle you're not accessing images directly. You get an url to ImagineBundle's action that checks if file exists in cache folder (which means it's already generated), and if not, it creates one.

Comment: This was already added to my routing.yml file:  
    _liip_imagine:
        resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

Comment: Composer did not create any new bundle (LiipImagineBundle) in my src/ folder. It just aded the files in vendor/liip folder. Is this normal? (I am using Symfony3)

Comment: Yes. That's how it works. If it still doesn't work, please edit your question and add LiipImagineBundle configuration. Also check if the file exists in the filesystem (Note that generated files may not be stored in public directory)

Comment: I added the configuration, it is the same with the one from the cookbook, the file exists in the cache folder and it is resized as it should be. I could see this only by moving the file in web/bundles/ folder.    My only problem now is that I can't access the file in the cache folder..